# How can I connect to a Postgresql database (which is on my local machine) using dbeaver on my virtual machine?

Tags: postgresql, dbeaver

I have created a postgresql database on my local machine and I want to connect to that database on my virtual linux(centos) machine. But I could not figure it out. What should I type in the host section ? (Link [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uYH5.png))

Comment: You would put in the IP address of your "local" machine.  Is your local machine also the host which is running the virtual machine software on which the VM is running?

Comment: Yes the virtual machine is running on my local machine.

Answer (score 1):

You need to port forward the localhost to the virtual machine using something like this [image] you need to enter your host and guest IPs and ports accordingly.